# Providing Webservices in an OSGi environment

Tags: java, web-services, osgi, apache-felix

I'm looking for a way to provide webservices in an OSGi environment. Does anyone have experiences and can point me in the right direction?

So far I know about [Apache CXF DOSGi](http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi.html), but I'm looking for alternatives as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is not only CXF dOSGi. You can also use plain CXF services. I have done a tutorial about using CXF webservices in OSGi. It shows JAX-WS and JAX-RS services. The easiest way of using CXF in OSGi is with Apache Karaf as there is a CXF feature which allows installing CXF with a simple command. I also recommend using maven and the maven bundle plugin like shown in the example.

http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/12/22/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+4+-+CXF+Services+in+OSGi

Comment: Hi Christian. Thanks a lot for your answer. Since I'm not using Apache Karaf as the OSGi Run Container in the future (will use JBoss) that will not suite for me. But its great to know there are more possiblities. Worst thing about CXF is the bunch of dependencies and without OBR or Karaf features its nasty to install them or have them all in your own OBR repository. But as I mentioned before, I will definitly collect all given proposals and will write a blog articel. Of course I will link your tutorial as well :)

Comment: I am also interested in strategies to make running cxf easier outside of karaf. So would be great if you could add a comment here when you publish your blog article.

Answer (score 0):

Marcel Offermans provided a great tutorial using [Amdatu](http://amdatu.org/components/web.html) which offers the JAX-RS API to easily implement RESTful web services in OSGi. Link: http://amdatu.org/howto/createwebapp.html

Comment: You are ;) Do you know something similiar for SOAP as well? Just want to collect all possiblities :)

Comment: To be honest, it's been a while since I've used SOAP (5+ years ago) and back then I used Apache Axis. Now you would probably use CXF or maybe you can leverage the classes that come with Java 6+?

Comment: the link seems to be broken